# Installing rmagic 2.12.2 with ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16 on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm trying to install the rmagic gem on a Windows 7 system and keep running into the same error.  Here are the specs:

**rmagic version:**  `rmagic 2.12.2`

**ImageMagick versions:**  `ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16` 
(I've tried ImageMagic-6.8.7-8-Q16-x64-dll.exe, ImageMagic-6.8.7-8-Q16-x86-dll.exe, ImageMagic-6.8.7-9-Q16-x86-dll.exe)

**Operating system:** Windows 7 (64 bits)

**Development Kit version:** DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx

**RubyInstaller:** railsinstaller-2.2.2 (Ruby 1.9.3)

**Environment variables:**

`Path = C:\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16`
`CPATH = C:\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/include`
`LIBRARY_PATH = C:\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/lib`

**Gem Install script:**

```
$ gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/include
```

**Summary of problem:**
The full error message is listed below but it seems that I'm missing the following functions: AffinityImage(), AffinityImages(), LevelImageColors() based on the following anomalies in the full error message:

```
checking for AffinityImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for AffinityImages() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for LevelImageColors() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
```

**Full error message:**

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/lib --
with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/include'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageM
agick-6.8.7-Q16/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/include
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for snprintf() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AcquireImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AffinityImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for AffinityImages() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for AutoGammaImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AutoLevelImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for BlueShiftImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for ConstituteComponentTerminus() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DeskewImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for EncipherImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for EqualizeImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for FloodfillPaintImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for FunctionImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetAuthenticIndexQueue() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetImageAlphaChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetVirtualPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelImageColors() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no
checking for LevelColorsImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelizeImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LiquidRescaleImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for MagickLibAddendum() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for OpaquePaintImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for QueueAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for RemapImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for RemoveImageArtifact() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SelectiveBlurImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetImageAlphaChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetImageArtifact() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetMagickMemoryMethods() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SparseColorImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SyncAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransformImageColorspace() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransparentPaintImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransparentPaintImageChroma() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for QueryMagickColorname() new signature... yes
checking for Image.type in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.kerning in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.interline_spacing in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.interword_spacing in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DitherMethod in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for MagickFunction in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for long double in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AlphaChannelType.CopyAlphaChannel... yes
checking for AlphaChannelType.BackgroundAlphaChannel... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.BlurCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.DistortCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.LinearBurnCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.LinearDodgeCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.MathematicsCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.PegtopLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.PinLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.VividLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT1Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT3Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT5Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.ZipSCompression... yes
checking for CompressionType.PizCompression... yes
checking for CompressionType.Pxr24Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.B44Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.B44ACompression... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BarrelDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BarrelInverseDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BilinearForwardDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BilinearReverseDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.DePolarDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.PolarDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.PolynomialDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.ShepardsDistortion... yes
checking for DitherMethod.NoDitherMethod... yes
checking for FilterTypes.KaiserFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.WelshFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.ParzenFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.LagrangeFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.BohmanFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.BartlettFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.SentinelFilter... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.PowEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.LogEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdBlackEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdWhiteEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.GaussianNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ImpulseNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.LaplacianNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.MultiplicativeNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.PoissonNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.UniformNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.CosineEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.SineEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.AddModulusEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickFunction.ArcsinFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.ArctanFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.PolynomialFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.SinusoidFunction... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.FlattenLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.MergeLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.MosaicLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.TrimBoundsLayer... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.VerticalTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.VerticalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.CheckerTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_frame_this_func() in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile


======================================================================
Thu 17Apr14 12:01:35
This installation of RMagick 2.13.2 is configured for
Ruby 1.9.3 (i386-mingw32) and ImageMagick 6.8.7
======================================================================



make  clean

make
generating RMagick2-i386-mingw32.def
compiling rmagick.c
In file included from rmagick.c:13:0:
rmagick.h:81:2: error: #error Specified QuantumDepth is not supported.
rmagick.c: In function 'Magick_colors':
rmagick.c:42:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'GetColorInfoList' from incompati    ble pointer type
c:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/include/magick/color.h:75:5: note: expected 'size_t *'    but argument is of type 'long unsigned int *'
rmagick.c: In function 'Magick_fonts':
rmagick.c:90:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'GetTypeInfoList' from incompatib    le pointer type
c:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/include/magick/type.h:98:5: note: expected 'size_t *' b    ut argument is of type 'long unsigned int *'
rmagick.c: In function 'Magick_init_formats':
rmagick.c:178:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'GetMagickInfoList' from incompa    tible pointer type
c:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16/include/magick/magick.h:129:5: note: expected 'size_t *    ' but argument is of type 'long unsigned int *'
make: *** [rmagick.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9    .1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86    -mingw32/1.9.1/rmagick-2.13.2/gem_make.out
```

The above settings work for ImageMagick 6.8.7 but not 6.9.9.  Here's a good resource that helped me get 6.8.7 working:http://www.ownway.info/Ruby/index.php?rmagick%2Fhowtoinstall%2Fwindows.  Unfortunately, it's in Japanese so you'll have to get Google to translate the page.

If somebody can explain why 6.9.9 won't work, please share.

Comment: From here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows, it has version ImageMagick-6.8.9-0.  Maybe it could work for you?

Comment: @GraemeMcLean, thanks for the link.  I went to the link and tried using all versions of ImageMagick-6.8.9-0 but none worked.  Using ImageMagick-6.8.9-0-Q16-x86-dll.exe, I got the same error as above plus, an additional one:  "checking for ConstituteComponentTerminus() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,
math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... no"

Comment: So I was able to get ImageMagick-6.8.7-8-Q16-x86-dll working... needed to set the following paths in my environment:  CPATH = {ImageMagick installation directory} / include and LIBRARY_PATH = {ImageMagick installation directory} / lib

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer to your question - it might help someone else with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard the error messages stated above and use the settings listed above - it should help you get rmagic 2.12.2 working with ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16 on a Windows 7 system.

Comment: `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1' --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q8/lib --with-opt-include=C:/ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q8/include`  here the commend which I was used. Please check the version.